# Decrypt Oracle CLOB Column having some special characters in it

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I have a Oracle table with CLOB Column in it, When i see the column in sqldeveloper in view text mode, i noticed encrypted special characters , my question is : Is there a standard Oracle package to decrypt the CLOB value to Convert them to English readable text.

**Can you help me with a simple select statement or a function where i can input CLOB and output ENGLISH Text.**

I do not have any history on how this CLOB is being encrypted.

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted special characters"? Really **encrypted** with AES or similar? Or just some "strange" characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how the column was encrypted or having the keys necessary for the decryption there is no way to convert it to readable text.

Comment: Thanks PMDBA, PLS tell me : What all details i need to have it handy for it to decrypt ? Pls list down for me......REALLY APPRECIATED BROTHER

Comment: i just know that --->> Oracle 128 bit encryption used and  ROT13 algorithm used.

Comment: You would need the original encryption key, and the specific settings used for those algorithms. You would need to write a stored procedure to call dbms_crypto with the appropriate values, assuming it has the equivalent algorithms to whatever performed the original encryption. If you don't have access to the original encryption keys, then there is no way to decrypt the data.

Comment: When the text is encrypted with Oracle 128 bit encryption and ROT13 algorithm then you cannot get the clear text - no way! That's the **main** purpose of encryption.

Comment: @PramodKumar ROT13? Is somebody playing a joke on you?